# Associated Voila files to finder by mistake

Tags: macos, finder

An associate of mine has managed to associate all his [Voila](http://www.globaldelight.com/voila/) files to Finder, and now he just has a bunch of folders for them.  He wants to revert this but, when he does, at *Get Info* he has no option to re-associate the folders/files to Voila.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: I need help to help... what is Viola? Or do you by any chance mean the screen capture software [Voila](http://www.globaldelight.com/voila/mac-screen-capture-overview.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You could reset/unregister Finder file associations with the following procedure:

- In the Finder, press
  <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to open the
  Utilities folder.
- Open `Terminal.app` ([image: Terminal icon]) in the Utilities folder.
- To unregister the associations, paste this into the Terminal window, followed by <kbd>↵</kbd> : `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -u /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app -domain user`
- To restart the Finder, type: `killall Finder`, followed by <kbd>↵</kbd>
- Voila documents should be Voila documents again.

Let me know if this works!